# Why Kotlin is not processing my list of Arrays

Tags: android, kotlin

I am getting data from a json api in my Kotlin code. I can parse the data correctly for string values but parsing the list of arrays is causing issues.

My response data is follows

```
{
    "limit": "10",
    "schedule": {
        "0": ["0", "3.00", "7.59", "9.00", "12.59", "14.00", "22.59"],
        "1": ["1", "3.00", "7.59", "9.00", "12.59", "14.00", "22.59"],
        "2": ["2", "3.00", "7.59", "9.00", "12.59", "14.00", "22.59"],
        "3": ["3", "3.00", "7.59", "9.00", "12.59", "14.00", "22.59"],
        "4": ["4", "3.00", "7.59", "9.00", "12.59", "14.00", "22.59"],
        "5": ["5", "3.00", "7.59", "9.00", "12.59", "14.00", "22.59"],
        "6": ["6", "3.00", "7.59", "9.00", "12.59", "14.00", "22.59"]
    },
    "target_temp": "32.18"
}
```

Now to retrieve the value e.g target_temp I am using following code successfully

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().create() 
 val target = gson.fromJson(body, data::class.java)        println(target.target_temp)
```

and my class code is simple

```
class data(val target_temp: String)
```

Now when I want to access the schedule I get the error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 50 path $.schedule

My code to retrieve schedule is below.

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val schedule = gson.fromJson(body, schedule::class.java)
println(schedule.schedule.get(1))
```

and class for schedule is

```
class schedule(val schedule: ArrayList<String>)
```

Comment: You should read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html though - doesn't fix the problem, but it's still important

Comment: Your data class does not represent the Json data you are trying to process. Eg.: data has no property `limit`.

Comment: I edited your dataset. you can see that your mapping class does not map the actual json structure.

Comment: @AlexanderEgger my data class is ignoring limit, since I don't need that bit of information

Comment: @shkschneider but I am retrieving target_temp value fine

Answer (score 1):

in your response model set `schedule` variable datatype `Map<String, List<String>>` instead of `Schedule` class `object` or  `List<String>`

your response model will look like below

```
data class ResponseModel(
   val schedule: Map<String, List<String>>,
   val target_temp: String
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Schedule is not of type `ArrayList<String` put of type `Map<ArrayList<String>>`.

Change your definition of schedule to:

```
class schedule(val schedule: Map<String, ArrayList<String>>)
```

Full example:

```
val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
val schedule = gson.fromJson(body, schedule::class.java)
println(schedule.schedule.get("0"))
```